# Search String with Regex, and Replace Contents with Data

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that includes values that I would like to have replaced from a JSON object. I have designated these values with `{{*}}` (ie - `{{bird.foot}}`). I have written some JavaScript, but am having trouble with:

1. Selecting only items inside each `{{}}`. I am selecting everything
   from the first set of brackets in the string to the last set of
   bracket in the string.
2. Replace each item inside the bracket with its corresponding value in the `data` variable

```js
var data = {
        bird: {
            foot: 'claw',
            mouth: 'beak',
            skin: 'feathers'
        },
        dog: {
            foot: 'paw',
            mouth:'muzzle',
            skin: 'fir'
        }
    },
    html = 'A bird\'s mouth is called a {{bird.mouth}}. A dog has {{dog.skin}} where-as a bird has {{bird.skin}}.',
    regex = /({{)(.)*(}})/igm,
    results = html.match(regex);

console.log(results);
```

Running the above snippet outputs the array with one element: `["{{bird.mouth}}. A dog has {{dog.skin}} where-as a bird has {{bird.skin}}"]`. I was expecting an array with the three elements: `[{{bird.mouth}}, {{dog.skin}}, {{bird.skin}}]`.

Ultimately, I would like results to output: `A bird\'s mouth is called a break. A dog has fur where-as a bird has feathers.`.

Notes:

1. The properties will not be in an alphabetical order
2. I am unable to use a Template library for my project. My project involves injecting code onto a page via Optimizely (AB Testing platform). I have access to only writing my own JavaScript.

Comment: To start with I'd change your regex to `/({{[^}]*}})/`, so that it will not match past the close braces (also this captures the whole thing as a single group, not three different groups). Better yet, if you know all your properties will be alphabetic, you could do something like: `/({{[a-zA-Z\.]*}})/`.

Comment: Use a templating library - that's pretty much exactly what you're doing. e.g. [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/). The correct regexp would be `/{{([^]*?)}}/g`.

Comment: Yeah that's the other thing. Regexes aren't a great fit for this problem.

Comment: @Amadan I can't use a template library for my current project which is why I am forced to do it this way.

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly My properties will not be in alphabetic order. They will be randomly inserted.

Comment: If you can't use a template library, you should specify why. Otherwise we'll just tell you it's silly because you should do it with a library :P

Comment: @Amadan I can't use a template library because my project involves me injecting JavaScript via Optimizely (AB Testing platform)

Comment: @Jon Sorry, I mean if you know that only alphabetic characters will be used in your property names, so no properties like `dog.prop1` or `dog["prop with spaces"]`

Comment: You can't inject the template library via the same mechanism?

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly My property names may have non alphabetical characters in it. No, I am unable to inject a template library into the page due :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = {
        bird: {
            foot: 'claw',
            mouth: 'beak',
            skin: 'feathers'
        },
        dog: {
            foot: 'paw',
            mouth:'muzzle',
            skin: 'fir'
        }
    },
    html = 'A bird\'s mouth is called a {{bird.mouth}}. A dog has {{dog.skin}} where-as a bird has {{bird.skin}}.',
    regex = /{{([^]*?)}}/g,
    results = html.match(regex);


// clean way, only for prop.prop.prop
var result = html.replace(regex, function(_, e) {
  var down = e.split(/\./);
  var datum = data;
  while (down.length) {
    datum = datum[down.shift()];
  }
  return datum;
});
console.log(result);

//evil way, more flexible, less safe, slower
var result = html.replace(regex, function(_, e) {
  return eval("data." + e);
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, I'm curious about this syntax: `[^]` - I'm not sure I understand it and haven't seen it before... is that a character class containing only ^, or a character class containing NOT (nothing)?

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'll integrate it against my code tonight and hopefully it will work :)

Comment: Re `[^]`: It works in JS dialect for "every character except (nothing)", i.e. every character. `.` is every character except newline, and in JS you don't get a switch to turn it off (`/m` only changes the meaning of `^` and `$` anchors, not of `.`), so `[^]` is a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

An object when passed to a function can get its property accessed via 'object["property"]'. I also adjusted your regex to '/{{([^{}]*)}}/igm' or else it with count this as one match '{{bird.mouth ... bird.skin}}'.

```js
var data = {
  bird: {
    foot: 'claw',
    mouth: 'beak',
    skin: 'feathers'
  },
  dog: {
    foot: 'paw',
    mouth: 'muzzle',
    skin: 'fur'
  }
};
var html = 'A bird\'s mouth is called a {{bird.mouth}}. A dog has {{dog.skin}} where-as a bird has {{bird.skin}}.';


function getProperty(object, propertyNames) {
  var regex2 = /([^\.]+)/g;
  var results2 = regex2.exec(propertyNames);
  var ret = object;
  while (results2 != null) {
    var temp = results2[1];
    ret = ret[temp];

    results2 = regex2.exec(propertyNames);
  }

  return ret;
};

function replace(data, html) {
  var html2 = html;
  var regex = /{{([^{}]*)}}/igm;

  var results = regex.exec(html);
  while (results != null) {
    var temp0 = results[0];
    var temp1 = results[1];
    html2 = html2.replace(temp0, getProperty(data, temp1));
    results = regex.exec(html);
  }

  return html2;
}


var str = replace(data, html);
console.log(str);
document.write(str);
```